# How do I approach equations like $k\, dx/dy = t - jx$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

How do I approach equations like $k\left(\dfrac{dx}{dy}\right) = t - jx$? I wish to find out an explicit function for $x$ in terms of $y$ and all the the other terms ($k, t, j)$ are constants.

My approach was to divide both side by $x$ and 'multiply' by $dy$.

But here I get a term like $\dfrac{tdy}{x}$.

I am stuck here. Please advise...

Comment: Please use MathJax to edit equations.

Comment: The equation in your question differs from that in the title.

Comment: Please see [How can I format mathematics here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) in our [Help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help), as well as further links given there.

Comment: Why do you want to 'multiply by $dt$'...? As $t$ is constant, $dt$ equals zero; multiplying both sides by zero results in $0=0$, which is certainly true, but hardly promising...

Answer (score 3):

This is a separable first order ordinary differential equation. Solve by [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20separation%20of%20variables,different%20side%20of%20the%20equation.)

$k\left(\dfrac{dx}{dy}\right) = t - jx$

$\displaystyle \frac k{t-jx}dx = dy$

$\displaystyle \int \frac k{t-jx}dx = \int 1 dy$

Variables have been cleanly separated. Now integrate the left side wrt $x$ and the right side wrt $y$. Don't forget the constant of integration (you only have to introduce it on one side - since you end up with $F(x) + c_1 = G(y) + c_2 \implies F(x) = G(y) + c_2 - c_1$, you can just replace that difference between the arbitrary constants by a single arbitrary constant $c$ on one side).

Comment: Note how he puts all $x$ and $dx$ on one side, all $y$ and $dy$ on the other side.  So he eliminates impossible-to-do things like $t\,dy/x$.